# Duplicate item errors when syncing a TDS project

Tags: tds

I am getting the following error messages when syncing a TDS 5.5 project:

> Item template with path ... already exists

[image]

> Found duplicate id ... for item ... and ... in project. Please remove one of these items from your project before attempting to sync with Sitecore.

[image]

This error happens for many items, and there are definitely no duplicates—neither in the project file, nor on disk.

This might have begun after I updated TDS to a newer version.

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Did you try the solutions from here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/750/duplicate-sitecore-ids-found-in-files-when-using-tds ?

Comment: Thank you for the link! That question looks similar, although the error message is a little bit different, and I think it's shown in the Output window, while for me the errors are shown as modal popups. The answers from that question do not work.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen that duplicate ID issue before but can't for the life of me remember exactly what the issue was. It _could_ have been something to do with whitespace and newline handling in the GIT repo (but it's a hazy memory as we've switched to Unicorn over here now).

Have you tried getting in touch with the TDS support guys? I always found them to be very helpful & responsive back in the day.

Comment: @OwenNiblock You're right, it could be related to GIT line endings. Maybe the TDS caching subsystem can't handle them properly. See the fix I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a reliable fix.

1. Go to *Tools→Options→TDS Options* and set *Background Cache Loading* to `False`.

[image]

2. Restart Visual Studio.
3. Set *Background Cache Loading* back to `True`.

Errors will stop after these steps—courtesy of Angel from TDS support.

The errors are caused by broken cache files. Changing the *Background Cache Loading* makes TDS rebuild the cache from scratch, hence fixing the issue.

Comment: Fantastic! This worked for me.  What a lifesaver...

Comment: any other way to work on this error. Above mentioned approach didn't work for me.